# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'RNFetchBlob.fs.dirs') on React Native for Android

Tags: android, react-native

I am getting `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'RNFetchBlob.fs.dirs')` when I am trying to download my apk file(with higher version) from the same app to update my application automatically.
I have already followed the [rn-fetch-blob](https://github.com/joltup/rn-fetch-blob) documentation and I tried to link the native module by both ways separately  to resolve the above issue

1. Automatically Link Native Modules by using this command `react-native link rn-fetch-blob`
2. Manually Link Native Modules by following the [documentation](https://github.com/joltup/rn-fetch-blob/wiki/Manually-Link-Package#index)

but non of the above steps are resolving my issue

I am using

- `react-native": "0.68.2"`
- `rn-fetch-blob": "^0.12.0"`

My React Native code are

```
import React, {useEffect, useState, memo, useMemo} from 'react';
import { Button, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import {NativeModules} from 'react-native';
const RNFetchBlob = NativeModules.RNFetchBlob;

const Startnow = memo(({navigation}) => {
  const updateApp = () => {
    console.log("App Update")
    const android = RNFetchBlob.android;
    RNFetchBlob.config({
      addAndroidDownloads: {
        useDownloadManager: true,
        title: 'stocksy.apk',
        description: 'An APK that will be installed',
        mime: 'application/vnd.android.package-archive',
        mediaScannable: true,
        notification: true,
        path: RNFetchBlob.fs.dirs.DownloadDir + '/stocksy.apk', //add
      },
    })
      .fetch(
        'GET',
        'https://kickstart-public.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/app/stocksy.apk',
      )
      .then(res => {
        console.log("==================Res==============",res)
        android.actionViewIntent(
          res.path(),
          'application/vnd.android.package-archive',
        );
      });
  };

  return (
          <View style={styles.descrip}>
            <Button
              onPress={updateApp}
              title="Update App"
              color="#841584"
            />
          </View>
    )
}
```

My android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml code are following

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.stocksy">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
 <!-- Change the value to true to enable pop-up for in foreground on receiving remote notifications (for prevent duplicating while showing local notifications set this to false) -->
        <meta-data  android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.notification_foreground"
                    android:value="false"/>
        <!-- Change the resource name to your App's accent color - or any other color you want -->
        <meta-data  android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.notification_color"
                    android:resource="@color/white"/> <!-- or @android:color/{name} to use a standard color -->

        <receiver android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationActions" 
        android:exported="false"/>
        <receiver android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationPublisher" 
        android:exported="false"/>
        <receiver android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationBootEventReceiver"
        android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
                <action android:name="com.htc.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service
            android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationListenerService"
            android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

android/settings.gradle code are

```
rootProject.name = 'Stocksy'
apply from: file("../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesSettingsGradle(settings)
include ':app'
include ':rn-fetch-blob'
project(':rn-fetch-blob').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/rn-fetch-blob/android')
includeBuild('../node_modules/react-native-gradle-plugin')

if (settings.hasProperty("newArchEnabled") && settings.newArchEnabled == "true") {
    include(":ReactAndroid")
    project(":ReactAndroid").projectDir = file('../node_modules/react-native/ReactAndroid')
}
include ':react-native-razorpay'
project(':react-native-razorpay').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir,   '../node_modules/react-native-razorpay/android')
include ':react-native-push-notification'
project(':react-native-push-notification').projectDir = file('../node_modules/react-native-push-notification/android')
include ':react-native-code-push'
project(':react-native-code-push').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-code-push/android/app')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your import of RNFetchBlob is wrong. You should import like this.

```
import RNFetchBlob from "rn-fetch-blob";
```

It is in documentation. Please follow the documentation correctly.